# Escape Special Character In Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud, faceted-search, solr-query-syntax

I'm getting following error while escaping special character '&' after running `http://localhost:8983/solr/amazon_products/select?q=*:*&fq=Category:"Toys \& Games "` 
this query in Solr

```
{
"responseHeader": {
    "zkConnected": true,
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
        "q": "*:*",
        "Games \"": "",
        "fq": "Category:\"Toys \\",
        "rows": "70"
    }
},
"error": {
    "metadata": [
        "error-class", "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
        "root-error-class", "org.apache.solr.parser.TokenMgrError"
    ],
    "msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'Category:\"Toys \\': Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"\\\"Toys \\\\\"",
    "code": 400
}}
```

Category field contains values like below

```
"Category":["Toys & Games "," Learning & Education "," Science Kits & Toys"]
"Category":["Home & Kitchen "," Home Décor "," Window Treatments "," Window Stickers & Films ", " Window Films"],
```

And category field is of type **string** with **multivalued=true**

```
      {
    "name":"Category",
    "type":"string",
    "multiValued":true,
    "stored":true},
```

How to search properly for **Category:"Toys & Games "**

***NOTE: I tried `http://localhost:8983/solr/amazon_products/select?q=*:*&fq=Category:Toys* AND *"Games "&rows=70`  this query and it worked fine, but If I excatly want to serach for string 'Toys & Games ' how to do that by properly escaping special character '&'***

Comment: queries that contain double quotation marks, use triple slashes \\\:
For query syntax: One slash \ to escape the "
For the JSON string syntax: Two slashes \\ to escape the \
Triple slashes \\\ escape both characters in \" to produce \\ (an escaped escape) and \" (an escaped double quote).

Comment: Getting error because of special character  '&' .  Double quotation is not causing any problem.

Comment: You don't need to escape `&`. https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/the-standard-query-parser.html#escaping-special-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to encode some of the characters. For example the following command:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/puldata/select?fq=title_t%3A%22Woody%20Herman%20%26%20His%20Orchestra%22&q=*&start=0'
```

will query `fq=title_t:"Woody Herman & His Orchestra"`. Notice how the `:`, `"`, spaces, and the `&` characters are encoded.

Comment: As suggested by @EricLavault no need to escape '&', escaping is needed for '&&'. So considering @Hector Correa answer, solved error by encoding '&'  with '%26'. Instead of   `http://localhost:8983/solr/amazon_products/select?q=*:*&fq=Category:"Toys & Games "` using this `http://localhost:8983/solr/amazon_products/select?q=*:*&fq=Category:"Toys %26 Games "` worked for me